# How can I set a breakpoint in a C++ static library from my C# project?

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, static-libraries, breakpoints

I have a static library written in C++, which can be downloaded in binary or compiled from source [here](https://www.openmicroscopy.org/ome-files/downloads/).  In that static library, I would like to set a breakpoint at a function [call](https://github.com/ome/ome-common-cpp/blob/v5.5.0/lib/ome/common/module.cpp#L404).  I have created a wrapper C++ DLL to that static library, and a C# unit test project that calls functions in that C++ DLL.  However, when I try to debug the static library, the functions are greyed out (see below), and I get a message that says "Source Not Available".

[image]

How would it be possible to step into the source code and set a breakpoint?  I tried using `Debug > New Breakpoint > Function Breakpoint`, but if I type in a function like `module_runtime_path`, it doesn't break at all.  Unfortunately, the current source doesn't allow for building from Visual Studio (it can only be built from Ninja).  If I build using Ninja, I've also tried adding all sorts of PDB locations but to no avail.

Is there any way for me to set a breakpoint in the static library?

Answer (score 0):

I can't pinpoint the exact solution, but I ended up building from source and setting in my C++ DLL project, in `Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Debugging`, I set `Generate Debug Info=Optimize for debugging (/DEBUG)`.  After that, I was able to step into the static library.